# Delete rows from a large table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, delete

I have a very large table and I must delete big amount of data from it until some point.

The table has only one non-clustered index on a column which is not relevant to use in my delete query. The first idea that comes to me is to include to the index a unique column which I could use in my delete query.

My question is, do you think it will be a good option or something better can be done?

Comment: *very large table* and *delete big amount*: drop the non-clustered index, run the delete and recreate the index.

Comment: Will my query run faster after dropping the index than it could ?

Comment: Probably, this is a common technique when deleting a large percentage. Instead of maintaining the index during the delete you simply recreate it when it's done.

Comment: how long can it take to recreate the index in a table with data space for more than 100 GB ?

Comment: How long can it take to maintain that index during a delete? You can run some tests on a smaller subset of the data.

Comment: You are getting some good advice.  It is pretty much always faster to drop the index and recreate for a large amount of data.  I have never seen that to not be the case.

Comment: Delete the data in chunks, using an existing index if possible.  Do not delete a large amount of data in one statement, or you will be waiting a long time for it to finish, and you may run out of space on disk.

Answer (score 3):

You should do 2 things for efficiently deleting the data from your big table :

- [Delete in batches](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes) and/or [do careful batching](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)
- [Watch out your Transaction log size](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/8-steps-to-better-transaction-log-throughput/) - if db in simple recovery mode - perform frequent CHECKPOINTS or if db is full recovery mode - perform frequent log backups.